error occurred during connection handshake ArgumentOutOfRangeException Specified argument was out of the range of valid values Parameter (delay)
What's cause this error specifically when upload on IIS not happening on local!!
this program.cs
using Core.Interfaces.Services;
using Core.Services;
using Core.ViewModel;
using Infrastructure.Models;
using Infrastructure.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Presentation.WebAPI.Extentions;
using Shared.Domain.Entities.Identity;
using SnapshotVideo;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Tawasol.Application.Extentions;
using Tawasol.Persistence.Extentions;
using Tawasol.Utility.CommonModels;
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;
using Tawasol.Application.Hubs;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

string connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")!;
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ShawtDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, Roles>
    (opt =>
    {
        opt.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
        opt.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
        opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        opt.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        opt.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        opt.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
    })
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ShawtDbContext>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

#region Api Versioning
// Add API Versioning to the Project
builder.Services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
{
    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
    config.ReportApiVersions = true;
    config.ApiVersionReader = ApiVersionReader.Combine(new HeaderApiVersionReader("x-api-version"), new QueryStringApiVersionReader("api-version"));
});
#endregion

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
                .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
                .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
                .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
                .UseSqlServerStorage(connectionString, new SqlServerStorageOptions
                {
                    CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                    QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                    UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
                    DisableGlobalLocks = true,
                }));

builder.Services.AddHangfireServer();
builder.Services.AddSectionConfiguration(builder.Configuration);
//builder.Services.AddRedisCacheSetup(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.InfrastructureServicesDI(builder.Configuration);
//builder.Services.AddJWTSetup(builder.Configuration);

#region Jwt Seetings using JwT Setup
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "~/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "~/Account/Logout";
}).AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    o.SaveToken = false;
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JwtSettings:SecretKey"]!))
    };
    o.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("access_token"))
            {
                var accessToken = context.Request.Cookies["access_token"];
                // If the request is for our hub...
                var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)) //&& (!path.StartsWithSegments("/api"))
                {
                    // Read the token out of the query string
                    context.Token = accessToken;
                }
            }
            // If token is not found in the cookies, check Authorization header
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Token) && context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();
                if (authHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    context.Token = authHeader.Substring("Bearer ".Length).Trim();
                }
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        },
        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Authentication failed: {context.Exception.Message}");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };

});
#endregion

//builder.Services.AddDomain();
builder.Services.AddApplication();
builder.Services.AdAuditUserAction(builder.Configuration);
//builder.Services.AddSwaggerSetup();
builder.Services.Configure<JWTSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("JwtSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<MailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MailSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<RegisterationMailSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("RegisterationMailSettings"));
builder.Services.Configure<PaymentServiceSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("PaymentService"));
//
builder.Services.AddLocalization();
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("ar-eg"),
                };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "en-US", uiCulture: "en-US");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.AddInitialRequestCultureProvider(new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider());
});
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Identity.Application";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    //options.LogoutPath = "~/Account/Logout";
});

builder.Services.AddSignalR(opt =>
{
    opt.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
    //opt.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    opt.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
    opt.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30); // Valid timeout value
    opt.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15); // Valid keep-alive interval
});

//
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
});
//
#region AddServices
//builder.Services.AddSingleton(new OpenAI_API.OpenAIAPI("sk-sFmby2_nFwzI-LeUK6jaOPS1ec4BTZqsOKbKsaX7EDT3BlbkFJE2V7QMrkdGWBQAQqXY0U260iq2EqkwCMFlP-RSsv4A"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IApplicationUserManagerService, ApplicationUserManagerService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMailService, MailService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ISnapshotService, SnapshotService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IImpotredDataService, ImpotredDataService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGroupService, GroupService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDepartmentService, DepartmentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IGroupEmployeeService, GroupEmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmployeeDepartmentService, EmployeeDepartmentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IErrorMessageHandlingService, ErrorMessageHandlingService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostService, PostService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostMediaService, PostMediaService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostToSelectedEmployeeService, PostToSelectedEmployeeService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostNotificationService, PostNotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPostAction, PostActionService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICompanyService, CompanyService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAdminService, AdminService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAppService, AppService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPaymentService, PaymentService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IPackageService, PackageService>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
#endregion

builder.Services.AddElasticSetup(builder.Configuration);
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(swagger =>
{
    //This is to generate the Default UI of Swagger Documentation    
    swagger.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
    {
        Version = "v1",
        Title = "ASP.NET 5 Web API",
        Description = "Authentication and Authorization in ASP.NET 8 with JWT and Swagger"
    });
    // To Enable authorization using Swagger (JWT)    
    swagger.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme()
    {
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
        Scheme = "Bearer",
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your valid token in the text input below.\r\n\r\nExample: \"Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9\"",
    });

    swagger.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
                {
                    {
                          new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                            {
                                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                                {
                                    Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                    Id = "Bearer"
                                }
                            },
                            new string[] {}

                    }
                });
    swagger.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First()); //This line
});

builder.Services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(setup =>
{
    setup.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";
    setup.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
});

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseGlobalException();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "AllowAllOrigins");
    await next();
});
app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseWebSockets();

//////app.UseRouting().UseEndpoints(r =>
//////{
//////    r.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hubs/chat");
//////});

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/hubs/chat");
});

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
});

app.Run();


hubs.cs
    public class ChatHub(IUserResolverHandler userResolverHandler, ITokenManager tokenManger, IChatManager chatManger) : Hub<IChatReceiveHubClient>, IChatSendHubClient
    {
        private readonly IUserResolverHandler _userResolverHandler = userResolverHandler;
        private readonly ITokenManager _tokenManger = tokenManger;
        private readonly IChatManager _chatManger = chatManger;

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            var userId = _userResolverHandler.GetUserId();

            await _tokenManger.UpdateConnectionId(userId, connectionId);
            var groupIds = await _chatManger.GetUserGroupIds(userId);
            foreach (var Id in groupIds)
            {
                await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, Id.ToString());
            }
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public async Task AddToGroup(string connectionId, string groupId)
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(connectionId, groupId);
        }

        public async Task SendMessage(ChatMessageDto message)
        {
            ChatReceivedMessageDto receivedMessage = await _chatManger.SendMessage(message);

            var group =  Clients.Group(receivedMessage.ChatGroupId).ReceiveMessage(receivedMessage);
        }

        public async Task EnterChat(string groupId)
        {
            await _chatManger.EnterChat(groupId);
        }
    }

packages
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="8.0.11" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Log4Net.AspNetCore" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="8.0.8" />
    
    <PackageReference Include="Audit.WebApi.Core" Version="18.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Audit.NET.SqlServer" Version="18.1.3" />

    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.AspNetCore" Version="1.7.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.Core" Version="1.7.27" />
    <PackageReference Include="Hangfire.SqlServer" Version="1.7.27" />

    <PackageReference Include="itext" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="itext7.bouncy-castle-fips-adapter" Version="8.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="iTextSharp" Version="5.5.13.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="jsTree" Version="3.1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MailKit" Version="3.4.3" />

    <PackageReference Include="OpenAI" Version="1.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mapster" Version="7.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Mapster.DependencyInjection" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="8.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="8.0.8">
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>

</ItemGroup>

I tested it by postman...
Choose WebSocket and enter Url wss://my-domain/hubs/chat and click on Connect
See image
enter image description here
Any ideas ??
Thanks
I try everything like:

Start from changing packages versions.
Uninstall all SignalR packages and install it.
Check the server to ensure install and enable WebSocket.
Testing on another server (Not Azure) getting same issue.


Don't set HandshakeTimeout to TimeSpan.MaxValue.
